# During gas-free transaction get an error "No relay responded! 4 attempted, 4 pinged"

Tags: web3js, contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation, truffle-contract

I did all modification related to this instruction https://github.com/tabookey/tabookey-gasless

However, when I'm trying to write some tests 
it fails and provides me the following error

```
     Error: No relay responded! 4 attempted, 4 pinged
      at RelayClient.relayTransaction (node_modules/tabookey-gasless/src/js/relayclient/relayclient.js:264:15)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

the logs are

```
relayTransaction: req: from:0xc.....
to:0x8f.....
encodedFunctionCall:0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000000949d494a5ca5afdbd2881d58b3804d9382a48db0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
gasPrice:2000000000
gasLimit:65000
nonce:0
relayhub:0x1349584869A1C7b8dc8AE0e93D8c15F5BB3B4B87
relayAddress:0x5b747ee070f18463e86ef08485e5115d82b675b9
relayTransaction: [object Object]
One batch of relays failed, last error:  No response matched filter from any server: [object Object]
```

Here is an implemented code:

```
    var tabookey = require('tabookey-gasless');
    var provider = new tabookey.RelayProvider(web3.currentProvider, {});

    it("test transfer gas free", async function() {

        web3.setProvider(provider);

        let initBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account_one)

        let tokenTestAddress = "0x8......."
        let tokenTestRelay = await new web3.eth.Contract(Token._json.abi, tokenTestAddress); 
        let result = await tokenTestRelay.methods.transfer(account_two, 100).send({ from: account_one, gasPrice: 2000000000, gasLimit: 65000});
    });
```

I use Ropsten network for tests relayHub is `0x1349584869A1C7b8dc8AE0e93D8c15F5BB3B4B87`

I sent funds for one of the relay addressed, however, this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

So found the reason:

**1. The contract should be deployed**

**2. You need to send a deposit**

you can implement own function in your [contract.sol](https://github.com/tabookey/tabookey-gasless/blob/29650374249ee8f17caddb3fe7613f0f42b91b63/contracts/SampleRecipient.sol#L16)

```
    function deposit() public payable {
        get_relay_hub().depositFor.value(msg.value)(address(this));
    }
```

or use external script like
http://gsn.tabookey.com/webtools/contractmanager.html

**3.  For tests you need to setup provider in a special for tests way**
 example from taboo key team [tabookey-gasless repo](https://github.com/tabookey/tabookey-gasless/blob/master/test/relay_client_test.js)

```
web3.setProvider(provider);
NOTE: in real application its enough to set the provider in web3.
however, in Truffle, all contracts are built BEFORE the test have started, and COPIED the web3,
so changing the global one is not enough...
```

```
TokenContract.web3.setProvider(relayProvider) - should be for tests only
```

Here is an example [gist](https://gist.github.com/svetlanama/fa09d31df68ab0c4d5fe942954b8f818)